# Where is the label on a ClipData visible?

Tags: android

It is possible to specify a label on a http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipData.html - but where/how is that visible to the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr: This label is useless.

I think that the label is never visible to the end-user.

In the context of the documentation, I believe that the user is actually the software developer.

What I find surprising is that you cannot query the clipboard with this label.